# Покажите пример UPnP запроса при двойном NAT

Tags: c++, qt, nat, p2p, upnp

Пишу на C++ Qt пиринговый чат (сигнальные сервера не предполагаются, сеть полностью распределённая). Как из кода клиентского софта послать UPnP запрос о пробросе портов на роутер провайдера? Обязательно покажите пример кода. И тут же второй вопрос по этому же предмету: по статистике 80% рядовых пользователей сидят за *двойным* NAT, т.е. первый выводит во внутреннюю сеть провайдера, а второй - во внешний мир, так вот - покажите, как программно послать UPnP запрос на *оба* этих NAT'а, чтоб пробить через них путь пиринговой коммуникации.

Comment: Тоже заинтересовала эта  тема. Есть сдвиги?

Comment: Пока нет. Если вы найдёте решение, отпишитесь, прошу вас.